# getting Exception: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisDataException: ERR Unsupported CONFIG parameter: notify-keyspace-events

Tags: spring-boot, redis-cache

I am trying to use Redis for the session in a spring boot application using dependencies like:

```
<dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
       <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-session-data-redis</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And the code for that like :

```
package com.dci.config;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.annotation.web.http.EnableRedisHttpSession;
import org.springframework.session.web.context.AbstractHttpSessionApplicationInitializer;

@Configuration
@EnableRedisHttpSession
public class SessionConfig extends AbstractHttpSessionApplicationInitializer {

}
```

This is another class for Redis connection and RestTemplate

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.dci")
public class RedisConfig {

        @Bean
        JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {
            JedisConnectionFactory factory = new JedisConnectionFactory();
            return factory;
        }

        @Bean
        public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate() {
            final RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<String, Object>();
            template.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory());
            template.setValueSerializer(new GenericToStringSerializer<Object>(Object.class));
            return template;
        }
    }
```

Comment: just add the code below to resolve this issue: @Bean 
  public static ConfigureRedisAction configureRedisAction()
  { 
   return ConfigureRedisAction.NO_OP; 
   
  }